# В/на намеченном маршруте

Tags: предлоги

Подскажите, будьте добры, какой предлог будет уместнее:

> Это первый крупный город в/на намеченном маршруте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**маршрут**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82&all=x), -а; м.
1. Путь следования кого-либо, чего-либо (обычно заранее намеченный и с указанием пунктов остановок). *Определить маршрут похода. Ехать по маршруту Псков — Новгород — Тверь — Москва. **Выйти на маршрут*** (начать следование по намеченному пути).

Предлоги **в** и **на** используются с винительным падежом при вопросе «куда?» (то есть при движении) и с предложным падежом при вопросе «где?» (и в первом, и во втором случае используются те же предлоги):
в Москву — в Москве, на улицу — на улице, на почту — на почте, **на маршрут — на маршруте.**

Обычно предлог **на** употребляется при описании горизонтальных поверхностей:
на поле, на втором этаже, на пляже, на стадионе (но: на стене), на маршруте.

Важна еще и связка союзов **в — из** и **на — с**: находиться **на** маршруте — сойти **с** маршрута.
Я бы выбрала предлог "на".

*Местные дороги подойдут также и для горного велосипеда – **на** высокогорном маршруте оборудованы места отдыха, велосервисы и парковки.*
***На*** главном мировом маршруте (о Северном морском пути).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Благодарю за правку — отвлеклась, не заметила.

Answer (score 1):

***Это первый крупный город на намеченном маршруте. Это первый крупный город в намеченном маршруте.***

Ответ исправлен.

В текстах встречаются оба предлога, например:

Первым **на намеченном маршруте** был Семипалатинский ядерный полигон  [Анатолий Докучаев. Охота за «призраком» (2002-2003) // «Воздушно-космическая оборона», 2002 | 2003]

Первым **в маршруте** был Тебриз, город на северо-западе Ирана. [Екатерина Колпинец. Путешествие в Персеполис (2016.06.23)]

Можно предположить, что предлог НА соответствует выражению "на нашем пути", предлог В соответствует выражению "в намеченном плане путешествия".

Comment: Странно. Маршрутная карта — это **карта,** показывающая лишь узкую полосу территории, интересующую потребителя, например, по обе стороны от дороги. https://geography_ru.academic.ru/3805/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0 Никогда мне не попадалось выражение "город обозначен **в** карте", только — НА карте.

Comment: Я не имела в виду конкретный термин.